# Using STIntersects to update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-query

I have two tables both with a geometry column:

- Table t contains trees
- Table ca contains polygonised conservation areas.

I'm trying to use SQL Server and STIntersects to work out when some of the trees fall within a conservation area.

After running my update query, trees that do fall within conservation areas still are being reported as outside. I think this is due to my conservation areas table containing multiple records.

A solution could be merging all the polygons in the Conservation Areas table, but I'm assuming there is better way of going about the issue.

```sql
UPDATE [TREES]
SET 
  IN_CONSERVATION_AREA = 
    CASE
      WHEN 
        t.[geom].STIntersects(ca.[geom]) = 1 THEN 'Y'
      WHEN
        t.[geom].STIntersects(ca.[geom]) = 0 THEN 'N'
     END

FROM [CONSERVATION_AREA] ca,[TREES] t
```

I'd expect the output to be 'Y' if a tree is in a conservation area and 'N' if it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining all trees to all conservation areas. Presumably no tree is inside *every* conservation area so what the final result looks like depends on which update SQL Server chooses to apply<sup>1</sup> (since there's a separate `Y` or `N` update applicable for every combination).

What we could do instead is a `LEFT JOIN` using the intersects test:

```
UPDATE t
SET 
  IN_CONSERVATION_AREA = CASE
       WHEN ca.geom IS NULL
          THEN 'N'
       ELSE 'Y' END
FROM [TREES] t
  LEFT JOIN
    [CONSERVATION_AREA] ca
  ON t.[geom].STIntersects(ca.[geom]) = 1
```

If a tree is within multiple conservation areas, this will still attempt to update *that* tree multiple times but at least all of the updates are the same (`Y`).

Note also that in this new form, it's got the potential to benefit from [Spatial Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-2017#methods), which you hopefully have.

As I said in the comments though, if you do have indexes, I'd suggest first testing whether performing this same logic when *retrieving* the data performs adequately. Prefer *not* to store data that can be computed - it just leaves open the possibility that it's out of date (when, say, someone adds a new conservation area)

---

<sup>1</sup>Some database systems will complain with errors along the lines of "row subject to multiple update!". But not SQL Server. Instead it's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#best-practices) to leave such rows updated in an *arbitrary* fashion.